# Django - Changing file name on ImageField

Tags: django, django-models

I have read other questions on this topic but none that actually answers my question.

I let users upload pictures when they submit a certain item to the site. Every user can submit  multiple items, and each item has one picture.

The thing is, I don't want to save the picture with the original filename. I want to save it with the item's ID. So if a user submits a Banana item, which is given ID 5 and the filename is

```
banana.jpg
```

I want it to save as

```
site_media/items/5.jpg
```

and not

```
site_media/items/banana.jpg
```

which is what Django is doing automatically.

Now the thing is, when I get the POST multipart data from the form, I already save the picture as site_media/items/item_ID.jpg. However, when I try to display the field item.picture on a template, it tries to access

```
 site_media/items/banana.jpg
```

instead of

```
site_media/items/5.jpg
```

Which is the file that actually exists. So I get a broken link.

I tried to change the picture.path property, hoping it was just a string Django reads from when linking the image, but Django gives me an exception, which drives me to think it might be something else.

Also, naturally, I would prefer if there is a solution where I just change the filename when saving, instead of removing the file with the original filename and save a copy with the new name, for good practice and efficiency purposes.

Anybody can help me with this? Thank you.

Models code:

```
class Item(...):
    ...
picture = models.ImageField(
    upload_to="site_media/items/",
    max_length=512,
    null=True,
    default=''
)
```

Here is the function handling the POST form:

```
item = Item.objects.create(... data from form)
try:
    picture = FILES['picture']
    print str(picture)

    destination = open('site_media/items/'+str(item.id)+".png", 'wb+')
    for chunk in picture.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()

    item.picture = picture
except Exception:
    messages.error(request, "Picture for item not loaded successfully")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. So, the problem is that `request.FILES` contains a different filename from the saved filename. So I just changed the `request.FILES` filename before saving the image, like this:

```
picture = FILES['picture']
FILES['picture'].name = str(item.id) + '.png'

# ...save as normal
```

Comment: This method will fail for new items that are not yet saved to the database, and therefore will lead to repeated code. Using the `upload_to` callback really is not that hard.

Answer (score 7):

You can provide a callback to the [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) argument on the image field. The specified function will be provided the current instance that will be saved. See eg. [this example](http://nomad.ca/blog/2009/jan/30/djangos-upload_to/).
The problem with this solution is, that a new instance might not have an Id yet, so it could make sense to use something like an [UUID](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) for the generation of the filename, so you can also easily avoid clashes if you would have more than one file for an instance! Have a look at the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) for generating UUIDs!